# Overlap analysis of buffers in QGIS

Tags: qgis, buffer, overlapping-features

I'm working on a project with 58.000 points. I've created a 14 meter buffer around all the points, and I now wish to combine the overlapping buffers into one polygon, keeping the non overlapping polygons in separate polygons. How do i got about this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create different id from buffer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/440962/create-different-id-from-buffer) - need to dissolve, but then that's the exact same question.

Comment: Yes, that did the trick! Thank you for your help :-)